# Styling ButtonBar font in Flex mobile app - with screenshot attached

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-mobile, buttonbar, flex4.7

I'm trying to add a [ButtonBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ButtonBar.html) at the bottom of a mobile Flex app by using this code:

**CSS:**

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

s|ActionBar, s|ButtonBar {
    chromeColor: #0066CC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    titleAlign: center;
}
```

**ActionScript:**

```
<s:ButtonBar requireSelection="true" 
             width="100%" 
             bottom="0" 
             skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TabbedViewNavigatorTabBarSkin">
    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <fx:Object label="Распасы" />
        <fx:Object label="Пуля" icon="{MONEY}" />
        <fx:Object label="10" icon="{CALL}" />
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</s:ButtonBar>
```

Unfortunately the font looks emboiled or blurred at the button labels (at the bottom of the following screenshot):

[image]

Does anybody please know, how to make the ButtonBar label fonts *regular* again?

I can not find the CSS setting for that.

**UPDATE:** I've searched the source code of AIR SDK (files like ButtonBase.as, Label.as, ButtonBarSkin.as, etc.) and still can not find the answer.

So I'm adding a simlified test case + one more screenshot below and a bounty for this question.

[image]

**TestApp.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               applicationDPI="160">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

        s|ActionBar, s|ButtonBar {
            chromeColor: #0066CC;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            titleAlign: center;
        }
    </fx:Style>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
            import spark.skins.mobile.TabbedViewNavigatorTabBarSkin;

            private function handleTabs(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                _tabs[2].label = String(1 + _tabBar.selectedIndex);
                _tabs.refresh();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="CHAT" 
            source160dpi="@Embed('chat.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('chat.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('chat.png')" />

        <s:ArrayCollection id="_tabs">
            <fx:Object label="One" />
            <fx:Object label="Two" />
            <fx:Object label="Three" icon="{CHAT}" />
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:ButtonBar id="_tabBar"
                 requireSelection="true" 
                 width="100%" 
                 bottom="0"
                 skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TabbedViewNavigatorTabBarSkin"
                 dataProvider="{_tabs}"
                 change="handleTabs(event)">
    </s:ButtonBar>

</s:Application>
```

**chat.png:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I've found that setting `textShadowAlpha` helps:

```
s|ActionBar, s|ButtonBar {
    chromeColor: #0066CC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    titleAlign: center;
    textShadowAlpha: 0;
}
```

And there is also `textShadowColor` available and used by mobile/ActionBarSkin.as, mobile/ButtonSkin.as and mobile/supportClasses/ButtonSkinBase.as

Comment: +1 this, now that I've seen your solution it reminds me of when I faced the same problem.